# left cyclic permutation

Tags: matlab

I want to make left cyclic permutation using MATLAB.
Consider matrix `p` :

```
p = [2 3 4 5];
```

Output :

```
[2 3 4 5; 
 3 4 5 2;
 4 5 2 3;
 5 2 3 4];
```

I hope the code is available for bigger data. Anyone please help me to make this in code using MATLAB.

Comment: thanks for you edited @Burkhard , could you help me?

Comment: I'm sorry, my Matlab is a bit rusty. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I think the `bsxfun` code for left-cyclic permutation in [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25857880/2586922) is quite right. You'll end up with a large matrix anyway

Comment: Isn't your "bigger" data is `p as 1 x 262144` from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857880/out-of-memory-using-bsxfun-matlab)? So aren't you looking to get an output of `262144 x 262144`? That's a huge number really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A loop free alternative:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:numel(p));
p(mod(X+Y-2,numel(p))+1)
```

Comment: +1 wonderful, I suggest to add the generic case: `[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:numel(p));
p(mod(X+Y-2,numel(p))+1)`

Answer (score 3):

This is one approach:

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(n) circshift(p,[0 -n]),0:3,'uni',0).')
ans =
     2     3     4     5
     3     4     5     2
     4     5     2     3
     5     2     3     4
```

Note that [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html?refresh=true) is really just a loop disguised as a one-liner. Thus explicitly writing out a loop to do the same thing might be equally fast/slow.